# OllyDbg: break on memory allocation?

Tags: ollydbg, memory

In OllyDbg, is there a way to break when memory is allocated?

Normally, I would just find a malloc call and set the break there, but that's not always available in the case of packed/encrypted/obfuscated code.

The memory map seems to only allow breaks on already allocated memory.

If not Ollydbg, is there another tool that can do this?

Thanks,

Geoff

- I've got my GREM, but I'm still pretty new to reversing.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `kernel32.VirtualAlloc`. If that doesn't work, put it on `ntdll.NtAllocateVirtualMemory`

Comment: You can probably set bp in msvcrt or heap functions in kernel32 as well

Comment: Thanks, this should work.  I was so caught up in the code that I forgot that malloc is just a wrapper for other lower-level system calls.

How do I formally accept this as an answer?